# Access a method with string parameters Java Native Interface

Tags: java, java-native-interface

This is the java constructor method

```
public Intersection(String id, double lat, double lon, int interType, int index, String legsFrame){
        setIntersectionId(id);
        setLatitude(lat);
        setLongitude(lon);
        setIntersectionType(interType);
        setIndex(index);
        setLegsFrame(legsFrame);    
    }
```

and I'm accessing this constructor form native side

```
 JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL Java_org_smartcar_serverdatainterface_shared_services_CppConnector_getIntersection
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jdouble lat, jdouble lon, jint direction)
{
    jclass class = (*env)->FindClass(env,"org/smartcar/serverdatainterface/shared/businessentities/Intersection");

    if (NULL == class)
        PrintError ("class");

    jmethodID cid = (*env)->GetMethodID(env,class, "<init>", "(CDDIIC)V");

    if (NULL == cid)
       PrintError ("method");

    return (*env)->NewObject(env, class, cid, "jjlk", 34.5, 45.7, 6, 7, "dgdfh");
}
```

but cid is getting null. how to access this constructor when is has String parameters.

Comment: Don't guess about native method signatures. Use the output of javap -s. It is never wrong, unlike what you've put here.

Comment: `egrep` is nice to use with `javap -s`. On Windows, get egrep via [Gow](https://chocolatey.org/packages/Gow). `javap -s org.smartcar.serverdatainterface.sharedbusinessentities.Intersection | egrep -A 2 Intersection\(`

Comment: `NULL` isn't very informative. Use [(*env)->ExceptionDescribe(env)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#wp5234). You'll need it between `NewObject` and `return`, too.

Answer (score 0):

I sort out the problem

```
jmethodID cid = (*env)->GetMethodID(env,class, "<init>", "(CDDIIC)V");
```

I changed this to

```
jmethodID cid = (*env)->GetMethodID(env,class, "<init>", "(Ljava/lang/String;DDIILjava/lang/String;)V");
```

now it is working fine.

Comment: As I said. You had it completely wrong, and for the reason I gave.